# Regex Help: Trying to get numbers following a specific string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to get the number that follows the string "WK" in a string like "TF_6502BoM_WK47.xlsx". So far I have this regex pattern /WK[0-9]+/ but I'm only getting "WK47".

Comment: Is the character length till WK is fixed?

Comment: Try it with a positive lookbehind `(?<=WK)[0-9]+` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QgccF/1)

Comment: Nope. The only guarantee is "WK" and then a two digit number.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That seems to work perfectly thanks!

Comment: Another option you have is to use WK([0-9)]+ and access the first capture group. The postiive lookbehind should work for this purpose for sure, but capture groups are definitely something you can keep in mind for future reference. i.e. if you wanted the number that follows TF_#### AND WK##, you could capture both within the same expression. Food for thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you ar looking for digits after WK and you expect any number:

(?<=WK)\d+ will do. This means: Look for any digit numbers preceeded with WK

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question is a little ambiguous, if you expand on your description we may be able to help more.

I've read this as you're trying to capture only the numbers? In which case you can do a named capture. The regex will parse the whole string and name the capture group containing the numbers so you can refer to it later in code.

```
var regex = new Regex("WK(?<numbers>\d+)");
var results = regex.Match("TF_6502BoM_WK47.xlsx");
System.WriteLine("Matched numbers: {0}", results.Groups["numbers"]);
```